# Skeletal animation for multiple meshes

Tags: animation, rigging, armature

I was wondering how do you make one full body armature, animate it and then apply it to different humanoid character. Currently I am working on several characters that will feature the same movements so I was looking for a way to do one skeletal armature and apply it to different rigs, that way I won't need to do the animations for each character. I've heard about the motion capture files that can be applied to already rigged characters however I was looking for a more personalized way of doing this by myself, if there are add-ons that can help me do that I'll appreciate the information a lot.
P.S. I'm new to do this so please no hate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every animation you do will create a - so called - "action" which is a datablock that can be transfered to any other rig. All the bones involved must share exactly the same names.

To understand the thing, try create a simple rig from scratch, parent it with a simple mesh, Shift D duplicate both object and armature and move the new obj-rig away from the original position.

create an animation of the first rig-object;
select the second rig, go to pose mode, open a dope-sheet window, in the header change the drop down menu from "dopesheet" to "action"; change the dropdown menu from "new" (2nd rig has no actions, by now) to the only one you have created.

Now, moving the timeline, both objects move together, as they share the same action and the same bone names.

Note that the action is referred to the local space of the object, so, if the 2 object have different positions, they will move as twins, in their respective position.

The same you can apply with complex models and rigs, if they share the same bone names.